# Why i'm getting runtime error in ideone and codechef compiler and not in my terminal?

Tags: c, algorithm, runtime-error

I have just started competitive programming in SPOJ.I'm confused from sometime why i'm getting `runtime error` in `ideone`.The question is:
A positive integer is called a palindrome if its representation in the decimal system is the same when read from left to right and from right to left. For a given positive integer `K` of not more than `1000000` digits, write the value of the smallest palindrome larger than K to output. Numbers are always displayed without leading zeros.
**Input**

The first line contains integer t, the number of test cases. Integers K are given in the next t lines.
**Output**

For each K, output the smallest palindrome larger than K.

Example

**Input:**
2
808
2133

**Output:**
818
2222 
**My program:**

```
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main(void)
 {
   int t,i,reverse,same;

   scanf("%d",&t);  //t is no. of test cases

     int num[t];  //num[t] is array of t elements

   for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    scanf("%d",&num[i]);

   i=0;     //since i will be equal to t therefore i is assigned to 0.

   while(t--)
   {    
    if(num[i]<=1000000)  
    {
    while(num[i]++)
        {
         reverse=0;
         same=num[i];     

         while(same>0)
         {
          reverse=reverse*10;
          reverse=reverse+same%10;
          same=same/10;
         }
     if(reverse==num[i])
      printf("%d",reverse);

     printf("\n");

     if(reverse==num[i])
      break;
     }
    }
    i++;     
   }
  return 0;
 }
```

I don't know where i'm wrong.I'm sorry i'm asking this question may this question is asked by someone before.I tried to find the result but could not get the answer.**Thankyou** in **advance** and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I already see `int num[t];` where `t` is not a `const int`... that's a problem.

Comment: i've many times used this type of deceleration but never faced this type of problem.Used in problem no. 2 in spoj and it successfully accepted.

Comment: @Jashaszun: Why is that a problem? `const int i` is just a variable in C, as much as `int i` is.

Comment: @Olaf Isn't it a requirement in C that array sizes be compile-time constant? If not, then I was taught C incorrectly (or I misremember).

Comment: @Jashaszun: Or you might have to update to C99 (or directly to the current standard C11) then: variable length array (VLA). But for the `const` you are confusing C and C++.

Comment: Make sure you chose "C" as your language in IDEone, not C++

Comment: @Jashaszun you must have learned more than 16 years ago... times change

Comment: @MattMcNabb Heh, I'm only 18 years old, so not quite. I learned C/C++ around 5-ish years ago at a UC San Diego summer class, so maybe they're just way out of date.

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't say that the number will be less than 1000000. It says that the number has less than **1 million digits**. A number with a million digits looks like this

```
591875018734106743196734198673419067843196874398674319687431986743918674319867431986743198674319876341987643198764319876341987643198764319876431987643198763419876431987643198764319876139876...
```

You can't use `scanf` to read a number that has a million digits, and you can't store that number in an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for your error to occur is some memory fault. Keep in mind that online judges/compilers limit your available memory and if you try to allocate/use more memory than available, you get a runtime error. This also happens on your machine, but usually you have a lot more memory available for your program than in the case of online judges.

In your case, you could reduce the memory usage of your program by changing the data type of the num array from int to something like short or even char.

Comment: but still after submitting the solution it is showing wrong answer.